# Android Notification.InboxStyle still shows default notification layout

Tags: android, notifications

Here's my code :

```
public static void pushNotification(Activity currentActivity, String title, String content[]){

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) currentActivity.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(currentActivity.getBaseContext(), FileSharingActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(currentActivity);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(FileSharingActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    nm.notify(nextId++, new Notification.InboxStyle(new Notification.Builder(currentActivity.getBaseContext())
                                                    .setTicker("Ticker")
                                                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                                    .setContentTitle("Content title")
                                                    .setContentText("Content text")
                                                    .setNumber(4)
                                                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent))
                                                    .addLine("First Message")
                                                    .addLine("Second Message")
                                                    .addLine("Third Message")
                                                    .addLine("Fourth Message")
                                                    .setBigContentTitle("Here Your Messages")
                                                    .setSummaryText("+3 more")
                                                    .build());
}
```

Here's the result :
[image]

Device is S3 running Android version 4.4.2.

Why is the InboxStyle not applied?

Comment: I assume you tried swiping down on the notification correct?

Comment: Damn it... You're right. I had to swipe the notification down to see the expanded info.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

```
 Notification notif = new Notification.Builder(mContext)
 .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
 .setContentText(subject)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
 .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
 .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle() //Style is here
     .addLine(str1)
     .addLine(str2)
     .setContentTitle("")
     .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
 .build();
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.InboxStyle.html

---

EDIT:

I do it like this in my Android Project:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(titel)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setTicker(ticker)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .getNotification();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    n.flags |=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

Comment: Nope, still same result. I tried all that before and I just tried your code.

Comment: Edited my post! Does this help you? Or do you need to use the notification style?

Answer (score 0):

I had to swipe down the notification to see the expanded information.

The code works just fine.